# Mnesia returns {aborted, no_transaction}

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I have a Mnesia table called `person`, using the following record definition:

```
-record(person, {id, firstname, lastname, phone}).
```

The table contains these values:

```
    12  alen     dumas      97888888
    13  franco   mocci      55522225
    14  ali      othmani    44444449
```

I want to retreive the last id  which is in my case  **14**.

I try with :

```
test()->
    Key=mnesia:last(person).
```

but when I test this function I have this error :

```
** exception exit: {aborted,no_transaction}
     in function  mnesia:abort/1
```

Why is that?  What can I do about it?

Comment: I think that erlang contains a function that returns the last object in same table

Comment: `mnesia:last/1` works. You just used it wrongly. However, ordering is not a good feature of mnesia. You maynot want to rely on its ordering.

Answer (score 4):

The error message `exception exit: {aborted,no_transaction}` is quite clear:  the function is expected to be called in a transaction context, and your code isn't. 
If you don't need a transaction, you can use mnesia:dirty_last/1 instead. 
Note that both mnesia:last/1  and mnesia:dirty_last/1 make sense if the table type is ordered_set. For other types there is no explicit order defined.

Answer (score 1):

Ppolv gives a clue to the problem: you need to call the mnesia functions in the context of a transaction i.e. an mnesia 'activity access context'. Not tested it but something like this ought to work:

```
test()->
      Getlastperson = fun() -> Key=mnesia:last(person) end,
      mnesia:activity(transaction, Getlastperson).
```